# Xcode: Simulator keeps refreshing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

When I run my Xcode Project in the simulator it always refreshes when I'm testing it.
What I mean by it refreshing is that it turns over like a page in a book and resets my application form the beginning.

Does it mean my application is crashing or something? If not, please tell me a solution.

I'm using the latest Xcode.

Comment: Does the Simulator reset itself as well by deleting all of the other applications you have tested in your Simulator? Also, does your apps code have something that does something like what you describe on it's own?

Comment: Just noticed then that it only happens when you click AND drag, and me being on touch pad it can happen quite easily. Do you know how I can turn this off? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you "clicking and dragging"?

Comment: The simulator view. It must be an in-built settings, but I want to turn it off.

Comment: Theres no such setting for "click and drag to reset". There is not even a key binding that you can assign to resetting the simulator. Maybe post code from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to help us see whats going on.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what's happening: http://i45.tinypic.com/2h82ybn.jpg

Comment: OK, Can you explain why this happens, and will it be like this on a real device?

Comment: Yes, if it's code related it will happen on your device too. You need to provide code form the controller this is happening in.

Comment: Added the source code to question description for you to check out, thanks.

Comment: I commented all the code I added to the project and it still does it. I think this might be simulator related, new update maybe that hasn't been noticed?

Comment: Nothing in that code points to the page curl animation. Maybe search your entire project for **`UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp`**

Comment: Nothing found. It's DEFINITELY not code, I created another blank project and it does the same thing, it must've be a in new update or something, but getting rid of it the question.

Comment: By "latest" do you mean Xcode 4.4 (iOS 5.1) or Xcode 4.5 (iOS 6)?

Comment: Xcode 4.3.3, I just noticed an update came out.

Comment: Well, your particular page curl reveals the same green area, so this is purely code related. Try searching other key words like "curl" or "pageCurl", os anything similar.

Comment: How is it code when It does same thing on a completely new project? I have no idea what this is. :(
Could be the default code, but that is to do with settings and preferences usually, ill have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because it was a Page-Based Application, should've been Single-View Application. Thanks for helping.